# Gradle dependency on project for all configurations

Tags: configuration, groovy, gradle, dependency-management, multi-project

I'm looking into using Gradle instead of Ant/Ivy.  I'm trying to create dependencies between my projects for all configurations, so that for example, `project1.compile` depends on `project2.compile`, `project1.runtime` depends on `project2.runtime`, etc.

In Ivy, I did this with the following XML:

**project1/ivy.xml**

```
<dependency conf="*->@" org="myorg" name="project2" rev="latest.integration" />
```

In Gradle, here's what I have tried:

**project1/build.gradle**

```
configurations.each { config ->
    config.dependencies.add project(path: ':project2', configuration: config.name)
}
```

But it complains that the `project` function doesn't exist:

```
> Could not find method project() for arguments [{path=:project2, configuration=archives}] on project ':project1'.
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
configurations.all { config ->
    project.dependencies.add(config.name, 
        project.dependencies.project(
            path: ':project2', configuration: config.name))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked great.  In order to make this piece of code available in all sub-projects, I added a function in the root project that is called like this: `addProjectDependency(project, ':project2')`.  My hope was to define something like an 'all' configuration that would do the same thing.  Any tips or feedback on my approach or a better way to make this reusable?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for a working answer to the same question in 2023:

```kotlin
configurations.all {
    withDependencies {
        add(
            project.dependencies.module("org.example:example-artifact:0.0.1") // external dependency
        )
        add(
            project.dependencies.platform("org.example:example-bom:0.0.1") // platform BOM
        )
        add(
            project.dependencies.project(":project2") // project submodule
        )
    }
}
```